# Ubuntu 21.04 has no frequent/all tabs in "Show Applications"

Tags: appmenu, 21.04

When clicking on "Show Applications" in Ubuntu 21.04, frequently used applications are displayed but I want that all applications are displayed. In previous 18.04 and 20.04 installations, there were tabs named "Frequent" and "All" at the bottom of the screen but I cannot see them in 21.04. How can configure Ubuntu 21.04 to either display all applications and/or show these tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Frequent" tab does not anymore exist in the most recent Gnome versions (3.38 and up). What also changed is that the placement of the icons in the Application Overview now is fully controlled by the user, i.e., there is no automatic ordering anymore. The user can now decide to place most frequently used applications on top.

Check carefully: all your applications will be there. Some of these may be included in a group. For instance, "Terminal" and "System Monitor" are grouped under "Utilities".